# MySQL - UPDATE query with LIMIT

Tags: mysql, limit, sql-update

I want to update rows in my table with starting from 1001 to next 1000.

I tried with following query:

```
UPDATE `oltp_db`.`users` SET p_id = 3 LIMIT 1001, 1000
```

1. This is giving me syntax error. Is this correct? am I doing any mistake here.
2. Can we limit update in this way?

Also, the rows that I am trying to update are having Null value for the column p_id which is having data type INTEGER. Due to this I am not even able to update using following query:

```
UPDATE `oltp_db`.`users` SET p_id = 3 WHERE p_id = null
```

1. Is my above query correct?
2. What can be done to achieve this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

When dealing with null, `=` does not match the null values. You can use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`

```
UPDATE `smartmeter_usage`.`users_reporting` 
SET panel_id = 3 WHERE panel_id IS NULL
```

`LIMIT` can be used with `UPDATE` but with the `row count` only

Comment: Thank you for the response. Can you please give me an insight of why IS NULL different from = null. Also. what exactly IS NULL does to find null values?

Comment: @srahul07: Because NULL is not a real value and `=` check for the equality of two values. Hence `=` does not match null.

Comment: @Framework, update limit with `row count` not working for mysql version 5.1.X

Answer (score 178):

If you want to update multiple rows using limit in MySQL you can use this construct:

```
UPDATE table_name SET name='test'
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id FROM (
        SELECT id FROM table_name 
        ORDER BY id ASC  
        LIMIT 0, 10
    ) tmp
)
```

Comment: MySQL 5.5 does not support LIMIT in IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery: Error Code 1235

Comment: @FiveO Works fine for me on MySQL 5.5.34. Without the nested subquery (the perverse `SELECT id FROM (SELECT id FROM ...)` construct) I get `ERROR 1235 (42000): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`, but if I include both selects as shown here, the query works.

Comment: By the way, for Postgres 9.4, this kind of code works without needing the outer `SELECT id FROM (` … `) tmp `. Thanks. Seems like this should be the Accepted Answer.

Comment: Yep, limit doesn't work with update. +1 for you, man :)

Comment: MySQL update is success, but For Mariadb, IN conditions are not allowed in the update command

Answer (score 19):

In addition to the nested approach above, you can accomplish the application of the`LIMIT` using `JOIN` on the same table:

```
UPDATE `table_name`
INNER JOIN (SELECT `id` from `table_name` order by `id` limit 0,100) as t2 using (`id`)
SET `name` = 'test'
```

In my experience the mysql query optimizer is happier with this structure.

Comment: I prefer this query using an inner join. Maybe harder to grasp, but definitely neater.

Answer (score 12):

I would suggest a two step query

I'm assuming you have an autoincrementing primary key because you say your PK is (max+1) which sounds like the definition of an autioincrementing key.
I'm calling the PK `id`, substitute with whatever your PK is called.

1 - figure out the primary key number for column 1000.

```
SELECT @id:= id FROM smartmeter_usage LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1000
```

2 - update the table.

```
UPDATE smartmeter_usage.users_reporting SET panel_id = 3 
WHERE panel_id IS NULL AND id >= @id 
ORDER BY id 
LIMIT 1000
```

Please test to see if I didn't make an off-by-one error; you may need to add or subtract 1 somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

```
UPDATE `smartmeter_usage`.`users_reporting` SET panel_id = 3 LIMIT 1001, 1000
```

This query is not correct (or at least i don't know a possible way to use limit in UPDATE queries),  you should put a `where` condition on you primary key (this assumes you have an auto_increment column as your primary key, if not provide more details):

```
UPDATE `smartmeter_usage`.`users_reporting` SET panel_id = 3 WHERE primary_key BETWEEN 1001 AND 2000
```

For the second query you must use IS

```
UPDATE `smartmeter_usage`.`users_reporting` SET panel_id = 3 WHERE panel_id is null
```

EDIT - if your primary_key is a column named MAX+1 you query should be (with backticks as stated correctly in the comment):

```
UPDATE `smartmeter_usage`.`users_reporting` SET panel_id = 3 WHERE `MAX+1` BETWEEN 1001 AND 2000
```

To update the rows with MAX+1 from 1001 TO 2000 (including 1001 and 2000)

Comment: You make the assumption that he has an auto_increment on the table, which might not be the case, nor does it have to be an unbroken series of numbers.

Comment: well, yes, of course i'm making that assumption, i'll update the answer with that, waiting for more information! :)

Comment: Thank you for response. Actually the primary key is MAX+1.

Comment: -1, (A) max is a reserved word, needs to be quoted in backticks. (B) `max + 1 between 1001 and 2000` should be rewritten to `max between 1000 and 1999`. (C) I've never heard of a primary key called `max+1` that makes no sense. (D) This code assumes column `max` is continous, which is not guaranteed by any means. (E) limit does work with `update`.

Comment: Great answer. Your first UPDATE query works perfect if you have a PK auto increment!

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with a LIMIT, just not with a LIMIT and an OFFSET.

Answer (score 1):

You should use IS rather than = for comparing to NULL.

```
UPDATE `smartmeter_usage`.`users_reporting`
SET panel_id = 3
WHERE panel_id IS null
```

The `LIMIT` clause in MySQL when applied to an update does not permit an offset to be specified.

Comment: This helped me in a similar but different situation - query should have read "update my_table set process_id = n limit 1000" instead of "update my_table set process_id = n limit 0,1000"

Answer (score 0):

You should highly consider using an `ORDER BY` if you intend to LIMIT your UPDATE, because otherwise it will update in the ordering of the table, which might not be correct.

But as Will A said, it only allows limit on row_count, not offset.

Answer (score 0):

For people get this post by search "update limit MySQL"  trying to avoid turning off the `safe update mode` when facing `update` with the multiple-table syntax.

Since [the offical document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) state

> For the multiple-table syntax, UPDATE updates rows in each table named
>   in table_references that satisfy the conditions. In this case, ORDER
>   BY and LIMIT cannot be used.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28316067/1278112
I think this answer is quite helpful. It gives an example

> UPDATE customers SET countryCode = 'USA'
>       WHERE country = 'USA';               -- which gives the error, you just write:
>
> UPDATE customers SET countryCode = 'USA'
>       WHERE (country = 'USA' AND customerNumber <> 0); -- Because customerNumber is a primary key you got no error 1175 any more.

What I want but would raise error code 1175.

```
UPDATE table1 t1
        INNER JOIN
    table2 t2 ON t1.name = t2.name 
SET 
    t1.column = t2.column
WHERE
    t1.name = t2.name;
```

The working edition

```
UPDATE table1 t1
        INNER JOIN
    table2 t2 ON t1.name = t2.name 
SET 
    t1.column = t2.column
WHERE
    (t1.name = t2.name and t1.prime_key !=0);
```

Which is really simple and elegant. Since the original answer doesn't get too much attention (votes), I post more explanation. Hope this can help others.

Answer (score 0):

The limiting column name is not given but assuming it to be **XX**, then something like this should do. It is tested on MariaDB 10:

```
UPDATE `oltp_db`.`users` SET `p_id` = '3' WHERE `p_id` IS NULL AND `XX` > 1000 LIMIT 1000;
```

This will target the right records. The only unknown **side-effect** is that although the *affected rows* show the *limit number*, the actual changes may be less.

Answer (score 0):

for 5.5 you can use sub subquery like this:

```
update table_A as ta
join table_B as tb on tb.cid = ta.cid
set ta.user_id = tb.user_id, ta.modified_at = now()
where ta.id in (
    select sta.id from (select * from table_A as ssta where ssta.user_id = 0 limit 10) as sta
)
```