# `UPDATE ... SET ... LIMIT` in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ddl

I would like to update a specific range of rows, say starting from `30` and ending at `50`. How may I achieve that.

I have tried with:

```
UPDATE tab
SET    col = 'somevalue' 
LIMIT 30, 50
```

but this doesn't work. Is there any way that I can update these rows?

The error that I get is:

> Check the manual ... for the right syntax to use near ' 50'

Comment: How does this not work?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: limit and offset don't make sense without an `order by` because rows in a relational database are not sorted

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your statement is not valid MySQL syntax *and* it doesn't make sense.  The problem with the syntax is that offset is not supported for `update` statements (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html)).

The problem with the logic is that you have no `order by` clause.  MySQL doesn't guarantee the order of tables when processing them.  So the "first" twenty rows and the "next" twenty" rows make no difference.

Why doesn't this do what you want?

```
UPDATE tab
  SET    col = 'somevalue' 
  LIMIT 20;
```

If you have a specific column that specifies the ordering, you can use `where`:

```
UPDATE tab
  SET    col = 'somevalue' 
  wHERE ID >= 30 and ID < 50;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think with update you can not use limit as it is in select(`offset` support), you will have to try like this:-

```
UPDATE tab
SET    col = 'somevalue' 
where id between 30 and 50;
```

`LIMIT` can be used with `UPDATE` but with the row count only, such as

```
UPDATE tab
SET    col = 'somevalue' 
where id > 30 
limit 20;
```

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289729/mysql-update-query-with-limit).

Comment: Nearly. It's OFFSET that mysql objects to.