# Stop query when it run by condition

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements

have some update query

```
Update
    some_table
set 
    some_filed=some_data;
```

How to stop execute of query when for example some_table.id>1000? Is it possible? 
Need stop, because write event for scheduler for very large table (over 30kk rows) and want to update only 10k rows for each time.

Comment: Add `WHERE some_table.id<1000`

Comment: some sort of where clause?  And 30k rows really isn't that big of an updte.

Comment: Yes, you can use LIMIT on update statements

Comment: over 30KK rows in table!

Comment: @winkbrace like in select?

Comment: Oh,you mean 30 million?  That's a little more than 30k :)  Trying to do that in batches is going to take a looong time.  You might look into inserting into a new table, and doing your updates as part of the select into.

Comment: @disable1992 Oops, my mistake. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289729/mysql-update-query-with-limit was suggesting it

Comment: @Andrew with performance of query (more difficult then example;)  ) all fine, 23k rows for 250 seconds. But need limit by rows count for each event start.

Comment: @winkbrace add your comment like answer and I choose it)

Answer (score 1):

```
Update
    some_table
set 
    some_filed=some_data
WHERE
    id <= 1000;
```

Use a where clause?

Comment: not good. Because it is event, and condition for id dynamically change