# How to select LIMIT mysql with bookshelf nodeJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, bookshelf.js

I'm using bookshelf plugin of node JS to execute mysql query. But i don't know how to execute LIMIT query. Like that

```
SELECT * from tableName LIMIT 2;
```

My connection bookshelf:

```
Bookshelf.mysqlAuth = Bookshelf.initialize({
    client: client,
    connection: {
      host     : host,
      user     : user,
      password : password,
      database : database
    }
```

and the data method:

```
bookshelf.Img = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'image'
  });
```

You can use this when calling for connection:

```
  var qb = data.Img.query();
  qb.where('img_md5', '=', imgMD5save).update({img_size: fileLength, img_local_url: folder, img_type: fileType, img_downloaded: 1}).then(function(){});
```

I've tried with

```
 qb.limit(5).then(function(){});
```

but it fired an error

> Possibly unhandled TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined

Please suggest any solutions for that.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing the operations you're trying to execute on your `qb` model, you're trying to run an `UPDATE` query with a `LIMIT` clause.

- `LIMIT` can be used with `UPDATE` but with the `row count` only.
- Reference this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289729/mysql-update-query-with-limit)
- Instead of using a `LIMIT` clause on your update, I would recommend strengthening your `WHERE` clause for an `UPDATE` query.

If your intent is just to run a `SELECT` query with a `LIMIT` clause, please look at the code snippet I've provided below:

```
var qb = data.Img.query();
  qb
    .select('*')
    .from('image')
    .where('img_md5', '=', imgMD5save)
    .limit(2)
    .then(function(result){
        return result;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        throw new error;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documention](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-query) you can write it this way:

```
bookshelf.Img.query(function(qb) {
    qb.offset(30).limit(10);
})
.fetchAll()
.then(...);
```

This will return a collection of 10 images starting from the 30th image.