# offset and limit syntax error

Tags: sql, mariadb

What is wrong here

phpMyAdmin

```
update posts set pos = 'right' where pos = 'below' limit 4 offset 10;
```

I also tried:

```
update posts set pos = 'right' where pos = 'below' offset 10 limit 4;
update posts set pos = 'right' limit 4 offset 10;
update posts set pos = 'right' offset 10 limit 4;
```

Always the same error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'offset 10' at line 1
```

Comment: You can't use `OFFSET` with `UPDATE`, only `LIMIT`.

Comment: Read the syntax here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: When you get a syntax error, why isn't the first thing you do to read the documentation of the syntax?

Comment: @Barmar, what a stupid restriction. thanks a lot.

Comment: MySQL has lots of silly restrictions.

Comment: Besides using LIMIT without ORDER BY is also meaningless because MySQL is free to return/update the records in anny order without ORDER BY

Comment: @bonaca - Why do you need to do it?@bonaca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Barmar said in the comments you can't make use of a OFFSET with LIMIT in UPDATE queries.

The best method to replace

```
update posts set pos = 'right' where pos = 'below' limit 4 offset 10;
```

Assuming you have a id column with PRIMARY KEY and auto_increment option.. this should work like using `limit 4 offset 10` or `limit 10. 4`

**p.s** Please note that the id's must be incremental from 11 until 14 without anny deleted id('s).

```
update posts set pos = 'right' where pos = 'below' and (id > 10 and id <= 14)
```

**p.s** this query will work when there are deleted id('s)

```
update posts set pos = 'right' where pos = 'below' and id > 10 LIMIT 4
```

Comment: This relies on rows having incremental `id` values, and will break if rows  are deleted from the table

Comment: indeed @Andomar edited mine answer so deletes within that range won't have a influence on the updated record limit

Comment: @bonaca i've updated this answer because off Andomar's comment.. Use the latest query because that one is more stabile when you use hard deletes on your table.

Comment: You can't rely on `id` being equal to the row's number. In your updated query, if one of the first 10 rows was deleted, the update wouldn't start at row 10

Comment: `.. and id >= (select id from posts where pos = 'below' order by id limit 1 offset 10) order by id limit 4` should work.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `posts` table has an `id` primary key, you could:

```
update  posts 
set     pos = 'right' 
where   id in
        (
        select  id
        from    (
                select  id
                from    posts
                where   pos = 'below' 
                order by
                        id
                limit   4
                offset  10
                ) sub
        )
```

[Example at DB Fiddle.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qFyNE1PSBpTBH2QJN2sHre/0) The double subquery is required to work around MySQL's `doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'` error. Like 
Raymond Nijland commented, MySQL usually returns rows in the primary key order, but you can't strictly rely on that without an `order by`.

Comment: "MySQL usually returns rows in the primary key order" Yes it's known that InnoDB returns in primary key order. MyISAM follows the physical order within the table data.

Answer (score 1):

**LIMIT** can be used with **UPDATE** but with the **row count** only.

So here below query will work fine without limit

```
update posts set pos = 'right' where pos = 'below'
```

Please check below links there are some good points for the same.

[MySQL - UPDATE query with LIMIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289729/mysql-update-query-with-limit)

As suggest by @Barmar, please check syntex and search little on this before asking here. :)