# Laravel 5.5 Call to undefined method stdClass::update()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Laravel 5.5 show me the error message:

> Call to undefined method stdClass::update()

for the following codes in the Model

```
DB::table('adminUserLogs')
            ->where('adminUserId', $id)
            ->where('adminUserOutTime', NULL)->first()
            ->update(['adminUserOutTime' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()]);
```

Comment: Try without `first()`

Comment: Can't Because I need to update the first record only with matched the where conditions.

Comment: When using the query builder, `first()` returns a `stdClass`, a standard PHP class, which doesn't offer an `update()` method.

Comment: Instead of `->first()`, could you try `->limit(1)`?

Comment: limit(1) -- works. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `->limit(1)` instead of `->first()` in the chain.

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel if you wish to update only one record then you can use `->first()` method of Eloquent ORM to get eloquent object and then you can simply update the object by `->save()`.

Laravel query builder directly not supporting update only record as Update with limit of 1 is not directly supported by mysql [MySQL - UPDATE query with LIMIT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6289764/1578380)

In the example you have given here is some modification to be work,

```
DB::table('adminUserLogs')
        ->where('adminUserId', $id)
        ->where('adminUserOutTime', NULL)
        ->update(['adminUserOutTime' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()]);
```

This will result in updating the records where specified conditions. To update specific record pass `id` column in where clause of that particular record.