# LIMIT in MySQL Update Row

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to Update Some row in my database. If I run without limit its working fine but if I run it with limit its giving me error like below

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '35' at line 1

My Query is like below

```
UPDATE number_list SET sync = 0 WHERE server = 1 ORDER by id ASC LIMIT 0,35
```

Let me know if someone can correct me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - UPDATE query with LIMIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289729/mysql-update-query-with-limit)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `limit` in an `update` (in MySQL) but not an offset.  So just do:

```
UPDATE number_list
     SET sync = 0
     WHERE server = 1
     ORDER by id ASC
     LIMIT 35;
```

This is a bit subtle, because `SELECT` supports offsets.  However, it is clear in the [syntax diagram](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) for `UPDATE`.

Comment: I want set offset in my query like LIMIT 35,35 and LIMIT 70,35 etc. Thanks

Comment: @RinaPatel . . . That is not the question that you asked.  If you have *another* question, then ask another question.  As I mentioned, MySQL doesn't support `OFFSET` for the table being updated.