# Using `limit` with an update sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-order-by, inner-join

I have the following query where I want to limit the number of rows it updates for the `subs` table. It keeps hitting an error though, where am I going wrong?

```
UPDATE subs t1
        INNER JOIN imp_subscriptionlog t2 
             ON t1.subscription_id = t2.subscription_id
SET t1.cancellation_date = t2.date

WHERE t2.event = 'subscription_cancelled'
LIMIT 35
```

This is the error:

> Incorrect usage of UPDATE and LIMIT
>
> Error code 1221.

Comment: *It keeps hitting an error*: please share the entire error message.

Comment: ___It keeps hitting an error___ Mind sharing that with us, it might be helpful?

Comment: 1) LIMIT without ORDER BY is lottery. 2) Use correlated subquery for new value. ORDER BY / LIMIT cannot be used in [multiple-table UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL - UPDATE query with LIMIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289729/mysql-update-query-with-limit)

Comment: The question is incomplete.  Based on the names of the table, I would expect the second table to have multiple matches for each subscription.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LIMIT` is allowed in single-table updates only, as explained [in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html):

> For the single-table syntax, [...]  if the `ORDER BY` clause is specified, the rows are updated in the order that is specified. The `LIMIT` clause places a limit on the number of rows that can be updated.
>
> For multiple-table syntax, `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` cannot be used.

You can rewrite the query to use a correlated subquery instead of a join:

```
update subs
set cancellation_date = (
    select t2.date
    from imp_subscriptionlog t2 
    where t2.subscription_id = subs.subscription_id and t2.event = 'subscription_cancelled'
)
order by ???
limit 35
```

Notes:

- you should be specifying an `order by` clause in the query, otherwise it is undefined which rows will actually be updated
- the query implicitly assumes that there is always just one matching row in `imp_subscriptionlog` for each row in `subs`; if that's not the case, then you must `order by` and `limit 1` in the subquery as well, or use aggregation
- we can also ensure that there is a match before updating by adding a `where` clause to the query

Here is a "safer" version of the query, that updates to the maximum date value available in the other table, while not modifying rows that have no match:

```
update subs
set cancellation_date = (
    select max(t2.date)
    from imp_subscriptionlog t2 
    where t2.subscription_id = subs.subscription_id and t2.event = 'subscription_cancelled'
)
where exists (
    select 1
    from imp_subscriptionlog t2 
    where t2.subscription_id = subs.subscription_id and t2.event = 'subscription_cancelled'
)
order by ???
limit 35
```

Comment: @Akina: yes, that would be safer, depending on OP's actual data. I updated my answer.

Comment: @GMB I've set the limit to 10 but keeping getting the error "Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction Error code 1205.". Is there any way around that?

Comment: @Rob: it looks like there is a concurrent process currently updating the table.

Answer (score 0):

Update sub1

Inner join
(

```
      //your select statement another table
      

      //condition

      //Now use limit
       Limit 10
      )
     On 
      sub.data = table.date
      set
```